# flutter: Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.1.2', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources

Tags: flutter, gradle, build.gradle

after update Android Studio to Electric Eel
I get this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/mohamedhamed/Desktop/connect_app/android/build.gradle' line: 19

* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.1.2', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:7.1.2')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
```

**for couple of days I try to update Gradle as show in documentation, and other solutions shown here, but still get the same error

Can I know what the correct settings for this situation**

my **app/build.gradle** file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3' //enter the latest version
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.2')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'

}
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.elearning.connect"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '2'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.1'
}
```

my **android/build.gradle** file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter {
            url "https://jcenter.bintray.com/"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15 '
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.20-RC2")
    }
}

plugins {
        id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.2' apply false
        id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.2' apply false
        id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.5.31" apply false
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
apply(plugin = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
```

Answer (score 0):

Based upon the official documentation for Android Studio and the Android Gradle Plugin, for Electric Eel, you need to update the plugin version to the 7.4 variant - see here [Android Gradle plugin and Android Studio compatibility](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#android_gradle_plugin_and_android_studio_compatibility)

Update the plugin details in your android/build.gradle file to:

```
plugins {
        id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.1' apply false
        id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.1' apply false
        id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.5.31" apply false
}
```

Also make sure you are using a minimum of version of Gradle 7.5